# How can I get price from html using regex in php?

Tags: php

I need to get price from html using regex. Below is a list of html and php code. I tried some regex code but getting some error. Please help me.

**Regex1:**

**html**

```
<p class="productprice"><strong>from  1.416,10 EUR</strong></p>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$subject = '<p class="productprice"><strong>from  1.416,10 EUR</strong></p>';
$pattern = '<p class="productprice"><strong>from  ([0-9]+.*) EUR</strong></p>';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $tokens);
var_dump($tokens[1]);
?>
```

**Result I am expecting**

1.416,10

**Regex2:**

**HTML**

```
<p class="productprice">
  <strong>
    <span class="productOldPrice">
      <small>Our previous price </small>
      <del> 1.416,10 €</del>
    </span>
    <br> Now only  1.299,90 €<br>
    <small>you save 8 % / 116,20 €</small>
  </strong>
</p>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$subject = '<p class="productprice"><strong><span class="productOldPrice"><small>Our previous price </small><del> 1.416,10 €</del></span><br> Now only  1.299,90 €<br><small>you save 8 % / 116,20 €</small></strong></p>';
$pattern = '<p class="productprice"><strong><span class="productOldPrice"><small>Our previous price </small><del> 1.416,10 €</del></span><br> Now only  ([0-9]+.*) €<br><small>you save 8 % / 116,20 €</small></strong></p>';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $tokens);
var_dump($tokens[1]);
?>
```

**Result I am expecting**

1.299,90

**Error**

```
Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '<' in D:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 8
NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regex pattern has to start and end with `/` followed by optional parameters. Also, don't forget to escape all special characters in your pattern.

```php
$pattern = '/<p class="productprice"><strong>from  ([0-9]+.*) EUR<\/strong><\/p>/';
```

You can use something like [Regexr](http://regexr.com/) to test your patterns. I have created one for you here: http://regexr.com/3f173